# How to read coordinates from text file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to process some imagery with specific coordinates. I have the most part of the script but the "read coordinates" part. For this, I put a text file with the coordinates in it; like this (just an example):

```
V2016057174800.L1A_SNPP.nc 30.1 30 -80 -80.1, 29.1 29 -79 -79.1, 28.1 28 -78 -78.1;
V2016057193000.L1A_SNPP.nc 29.1 29 -79 -79.1, 28.1 28 -78 -78.1;
V2016297193000.L1A_SNPP.nc 28.1 28 -78 -78.1;
```

But I am having problems reading it in bash and naming the variables (north, south, west,east). I don't have idea what is the best way to do this, but I have the following code so far:

```
while read L1Afullname; do

    L1Aname=${L1Afullname##*/}
    L1Aname=${L1Aname%.*.*}
    echo "$L1Aname"

while read $L1Aname north south west east in $Coordinates; do
    north=${L1Aname*/}
```

Any suggestions/questions? This is under development still,..

Comment: Could you give us specific example data?

Comment: _"I put a .txt file with the coordinates in it."_  Show us exactly what this text file looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll work with the case you have multiple image cordinates in your `file.txt` file. In this case you can save the coordinates of each image in each line of the document, starting the line with the name of the image. Ex:

```
Name1 north1 south1 west1 east1
Name2 north2 south2 west2 east2
...
```

In your bash you have to create a while that will read your file, and save each line components in a variable, like this:

```
while read name north south west east
do
   #your code
done < file.txt;
```

Then you can process multiple images and get all information about each image.

Comment: It seems I have an error in here: 


`while IFS="" read -r $L1Aname north south east west || [[ -n "$L1Aname north south east west" ]] in $coord; do
 Nlat="$north"  #name variable north
 Slat="$south"  #name variable south
 Elon="$east"  #name variable east
 Wlon="$west" #name variable west
done < "$coord";`

This is the error:
./script5.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `in'
./script5.sh: line 59: `while IFS="" read -r $L1Aname north south east west || [[ -n "$L1Aname north south east west" ]] in $coord; do'